# Can anyone with part of the chain (e.g. a light node) read unencrypted transaction data?

Tags: blockchain, storage, raw-transaction, light-clients

I need clarification on the fact that "the blockchain is public and anyone can read it".

Given a node which is storing only, say, 1 block from the blockchain, can that node read the transaction data from within the block without downloading the rest of the chain?

Sorry if this is a stupid question - is unencrypted data always stored as plaintext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A block is a well-ordered set of transactions that are plainly readable, as well as header information containing metadata such as the previous block hash for block ordering purposes. I should mention that a single block is insufficient to confirm the authenticity of the block itself.

Transactions contain some fields (partial list) such as `from`, `to`, `amount` and `data`. `from` is an address that signed the transaction and `amount` is ETH sent. Those are plain to see. A single block is insufficient to interpret `to` and `data` in every case.

`to` may be a contract. Without knowledge of what the contract does (the code), this is ambiguous, but it is sufficient to catch transactions directed to a particular address. `data` is also ambiguous because it gains meaning through interpretation by the receiver. The first 4 bytes may be a function signature if the transaction is directed to a contract. The remaining n bytes correspond to a field layout defined in a contract function. This will be hard to interpret in every case without the knowledge of the `to` contract. In an idealized form, that knowledge comes from interpreting a previous block that contains a deployment transaction with bytecode (roughly, `to: 0x0, data: bytecode`) for the contract of interest.

If one is interested in a narrow band of contracts (say, ERC20 token transfers), then one does indeed "have knowledge of the contract" - the function signatures and field layouts.

Some contracts will deliberately obfuscate `data` by encrypting client-side before data is sent to a blockchain precisely because plain data is readable by everyone.

Hope it helps.